# How to use tsconfig path aliases for libraries (Angular MonoRepo) without build

Tags: angular

I have an Angular MonoRepo. Within this is the main App project, which is supported by several libraries.

Currently, the above are using tsconfig paths `dist/{library_name}` for references. This setup requires building libraries when changes to their code occurs. For distribution, I appreciate this is needed.

For development, I would prefer to change tsconfig paths to the library source files, so that when changes are made the application (`ng serve`) auto-rebuilds. This would allow changes to be made more quickly.

I have tried to change the path to the library src files as follows:

```
"./projects/module-system/src"
"projects/module-system/src"
"../projects/module-system/src"
"../../projects/module-system/src"
```

The base URL is set to:

```
"baseUrl": "./"
```

All of these lead to "module not found" errors.

Is this possible in Angular? If so, what is the correct tsconfig setup?

Comment: Consider using https://nx.dev/angular

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible in Angular, on your tsconfig.json update your lib alias to:

```
      "module-system": [
        "projects/module-system/src/public-api.ts"
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could also use is the `watch` option. So you could run

```
ng build your-library --watch
```

This way it will detect the changes that you made.